# How to separate strings of unequal length into mutliple rows?

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

Is there a way to split columns with unequal length comma separated strings into multiple rows?

The data frame is as follows

```
names <- c("Inner", "Outer", "Median")
value1 <- c("1.3,1.9,2.8,1.0", "0.1,0.35,1.93,9.31,7.19,3.29,6.70", "0.12,8.32,9.10,11.10")
value2 <- c("56.9,60.1,1.0,9.8", "93.53,0.87,0.65,0.98,8.91,11.12,1.93", "3.10,1.85,2.30,10.19")

df <- data.frame(names, value1, value2)
```

The desired result is the following

```
names   value1   value2
Inner   1.3      56.9
Inner   1.9      60.1
Inner   2.8      1.0
Inner   1.0      9.8
Outer   0.1      93.53
Outer   0.35     0.87
Outer   1.93     0.65
Outer   9.31     0.98
Outer   7.19     8.91
Outer   3.29     11.12
Outer   6.70     1.93
Median  0.12     3.10
Median  8.32     1.85
Median  9.10     2.30
Median  11.10    10.19
Median  9.19     1.38
```

What's been tried:

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(value1, value2)
```

and that doesn't work giving the error

```
Error in tidyr_size2(): ! Incompatible lengths: 3, 2.
```

Tried setting the fill to both left and right without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

see a solution using `tidyr`

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# SOLUTION
df %>%  
  separate_rows(value1, value2)


# OUTPUT - updated 2022-12-12
df %>%  
  separate_rows(value1, value2)
#> # A tibble: 15 × 3
#>    names  value1 value2
#>    <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#>  1 Inner  1.3    56.9  
#>  2 Inner  1.9    60.1  
#>  3 Inner  2.8    1.0   
#>  4 Inner  1.0    9.8   
#>  5 Outer  0.1    93.53 
#>  6 Outer  0.35   0.87  
#>  7 Outer  1.93   0.65  
#>  8 Outer  9.31   0.98  
#>  9 Outer  7.19   8.91  
#> 10 Outer  3.29   11.12 
#> 11 Outer  6.70   1.93  
#> 12 Median 0.12   3.10  
#> 13 Median 8.32   1.85  
#> 14 Median 9.10   2.30  
#> 15 Median 11.10  10.19
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I've tried this solution and get this error each time: 
Error in `tidyr_size2()`:
! Incompatible lengths: 3, 2.

Comment: that happens because the length is not the same for some of the strings. try adding `fill = "right"` in `separate_rows()` (or "left" and see the difference), or correct them to have the same length.

Comment: Tried that as well and it gives the error of 
Error in `separate_rows()`:
! Arguments in `...` must be
  passed by position, not name.
x Problematic argument:
* fill = "left"

Comment: like this `df %>% separate_rows(value1, value2, fill = "right")`?

Comment: Yes, 100% like that.

Comment: can you create an example dataset similar to yours to give this error? because I didn't find it when using your example dataset.

Comment: Yes, will update the question with that.

Comment: It's been updated.

Comment: @user20751152, I've used your updated dataset and got the correct output with the same code I've suggested before. See my response.